# Special characters in CakePHP URL

Tags: php, url, cakephp, special-characters

I'm developing a web application where users have profiles, and skills related to that profile. I want to develop a page where a user can see all profiles that correspond to a particular skill. For example, if I wanted to see all users with the skill of "HTML" I could use `http://site.com/skills/HTML`. Pretty simple.

I've got it working, however some users have skills with spaces (for example `project management`) and some have special characters (for example `C#`). When I browse to a URL like `http://site.com/skills/C#`, Cake automatically makes it `http://site.com/skills/C` because it parses out the special character (`#` in this case).

How can I safely allow skills in the URL that have special characters in them? This is the action I'm currently using:

```
public function view($name) {
    // Find skill using $name
    $skill = $this->Skill->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array('Skill.name' => $name)
    ));

    if(!$skill) {
        // Skill doesn't exist, return 404
        // TODO: route to 404 page
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }

    $this->set('skill', $skill);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#` is a "special" character that by default jumps to a named anchor. In order to use special characters in an URL, you will need to use [urlencode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

But please note that your URL's will not look "fancy", it will just be encoded to the raw HTML entity of the special character. In your case `C#` will become `C%23`. So you might want to consider using a different URL alias for your tag, like `CSharp` (you can just set a "background" database field to "translate" the original value to an URL-friendly one).

Comment: Perfectly pretty URLs aren't a necessity, I was just wondering if Cake had a special way to deal with it rather than `urlencode()`. I've changed it now and it works fine, thank you :)